# Import problem in pycharm with django tutorial

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Yesterday I started learning django with this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMG4r03G6g8

But I am getting an `Import Error` here:

file: `django_1/src/dj30/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from posts.views import post_list_view # ERROR LINE

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('posts/', post_list_view)
]
```

This is my directory tree:

[image]

I assume that the `Import Error` occurs because I am trying to import `posts.views.post_list_view` from `posts/views.py` into `dj30/urls.py` which is in another directory. How does the guy in the tutorial do it? I am positive that I followed the tutorial correctly (I did it twice). Maybe there is a problem with `venv` because I am using `PyCharm` (com) and he is not.

Here are relevant files that were edited during the tutorial:

`django/src/dj30/settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for dj30 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'z=5t$_w+c@k3u+e1c-1tn6xoolrm#*ki*#@kh1u_*=rmwxtk!s'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dj30.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dj30.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

`django_1/src/dj30/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from posts.views import post_list_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('posts/', post_list_view)
]
```

`django_1/src/posts/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`django_1/src/posts/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

`django_1/src/posts/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Post

# Create your views here.


def post_list_view(request):
    post_objects = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'post_objects': post_objects
    }

    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

`django_1/src/posts/templates/posts/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the list of all posts.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

When I try to run `urls.py` this error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/django_1/src/dj30/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from posts.views import post_list_view
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'posts'
```

Running `manage.py` with `runserver` produces this website:

[image]

When I comment out:

```
from posts.views import post_list_view
```

and

```
path('posts/', post_list_view)
```

the site is shown correctly:

[image]

**Edit_2:**

Going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/` as suggested shows this:

[image]

**Edit_3:**

Changing `urls.py` to:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from posts.views import post_list_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('posts/', post_list_view),
    path('/', post_list_view)
]
```

produces this output:

```
C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\django_1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/django_1/src/manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

    WARNINGS:
    ?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '/' has a route beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'.
    
    System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
    October 18, 2020 - 09:44:14
    Django version 3.1.2, using settings 'dj30.settings'
    Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

and this website:

[image]

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/`.

Comment: @aaron please see the edit section. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/` seems to show the correct output. Does that mean the import works? Why is pycharm marking the import line red? And why is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` giving `page not found error`

Comment: See *silvermat*'s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm is marking the line red, because it is not aware of the application base directory. You need to click on 'src' and mark the directory as a sources root for this error to vanish.

Application is giving "file not found error" because in your main url file "dj30/urls.py" you do not specify the path for "", you just have "posts/" and "admin/" there. To solve it, you can simply add another path:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from posts.views import post_list_view # ERROR LINE

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('posts/', post_list_view),
    path('', post_list_view),
]
```

But I would not consider it an error.

And I don't believe that you would ever want to run 'urls.py' file by its own.

Comment: I marked marked `src` ad `source root` and it solved the red marking. How would I solve the path problem?

Comment: I added the path you mentioned but the site still give the `page not found error`. please see the `Edit_3` section.

Comment: Change `'/'` to `''`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from posts import views as posts_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('posts/', posts_views.post_list_view)
]
```